# insert HttpInputStream into a OutputStream in groovy

Tags: groovy, inputstream, outputstream

Was if there's a difference in Groovy between

```
IOUtils.copyLarge(content, output)
```

And

```
output << content
```

Where output is an OutputStream object and content is a HttpInputStream.

Also, hope I'm doing it right to get back the information from the connection

```
def connection = (HttpURLConnection)(new URL(myURL).openConnection())
def content = connection.getContent()
```

Thanks in advance for the tips !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're referring to `IOUtils` from Apache's commons-io library, a look into the respective sources reveals a key difference between Apache's `IOUtils.copyLarge` and Groovy's `OutputStream.leftShift` (a.k.a `<<`), namely that Groovy's calls `Thread.yield();`:

https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/IOGroovyMethods.java#L207

In this case when nothing is read from the `InputStream` but it hasn't reached the end of it yet the thread will pause, allowing other threads to continue whereas IOUtils will simply block its thread until it's done processing the `InputStream`. This means that Groovy's `<<` operator may behave differently then `IOUtils.copyLarge` depending on what other threads you have operating at that time and their relative priority.

`HttpURLConnection.getContent()` actually returns type of `Object`. This could be an `HttpInputStream`, but it might not be so you should be verifying the type of that object with:

```
if (content instanceof HttpInputStream) {
    output << content
} else {
    // Handle error condition
}
```

Comment: I see, so for speed purposes, I should be using the OutputStream.leftShift (it's what I understand) ? For the HttpURLConnection and the getContent() method, I can then get back a String instead then (which would make it a lot more easier for me actually) ? Thanks for the tip on verifying the type too !